# О "глоких куздрах"

Tags: лингвистика

Думаю, все знают лингвистические сказки, вроде истории о "глокой куздре" или "пуськах бятых". Там все слова вымышленные, но употреблены в правильных падежах.
Если честно, я не понимаю, в чем смысл такого коверканья языка, когда можно придумывать в качестве грамматических примеров и упражнений вполне осмысленные рассказики и предложения.
Я понимаю, что Льюис Кэрролл написал про "хлифких шурков", чтобы подчеркнуть абсурдность Страны Чудес, но остальные-то зачем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all_bakas, почитайте Успенского, там история Глокой Куздры изложена весьма популярно, хотя и несколько против реальных событий: Щерба свою фразу "шлифовал" несколько лет, а не экспромтом выдал.
Вот [здесь](http://www.e-reading.ws/bookreader.php/58817/Uspenskiii_-_Slovo_o_slovah.html) хотя бы.

Щерба учил студентов основам грамматики, т.е. *форме* языка, которая наполняется содержимым - конкретными словами.

Что касается художественной литературы, то этот прием, "корнесловие" (термин футуризма), этакие "макаронизмы наоборот", известен очень давно, каждый автор использует его с разными целями. Кэррол, как Вы верно сказали, подчеркивал абсурдность ситуации, но не забывайте, что он писал на английском, там грамматика принципиально другая, ни "кудры", ни "пусек" там не получится никак. Что до Петрушевской, то шут её знает, чего она добивалась. Я не отношу "пусек" к удачному произведению.

Answer (score 5):

Эти
 "сказки" используются для того, чтобы наглядно показать ту роль, 
которую в понимании речи играют некорневые морфемы.

Мы не знаем, что такое *глокая куздра*, но, исходя из состава слова, можем 
утверждать, что перед нами прилагательное и существительное женского рода 
единственного числа в именительном падеже (есть предложения-перевертыши,
 где под те же морфемы подогнаны слова других частей речи, но это уже 
отдельная история).

Comment: >Эти "сказки" используются для того, чтобы наглядно показать ту роль, которую в понимании речи играют некорневые морфемы.  
   
Это справедливо только к исходной фразы Щербы. Вообще говоря, каждый изобретает этот полумакаронический язык (у него есть какое-то название, запамятовал) с разными целями. Да и у Щербы цель была не столь узкой. Он не только и даже не столько "наглядно показывал роль некорневых морфем", он прежде всего демонстрировал возможность абстрактного подхода в лингвистике, существование синтаксиса как самостоятельного раздела грамматики.

Answer (score 4):

> > Если честно, я не понимаю, в чем смысл такого коверканья языка, когда можно придумывать в качестве грамматических примеров и упражнений вполне осмысленные рассказики и предложения.

Где эти "осмысленные примеры" и где "глокая куздра"? Она уже давно стала классикой.
Ведь очень многие считают, что язык – это корни. Щерба блестяще показал, что язык – это прежде всего грамматика. Смотрите, какая информативная фраза, а между тем корни-то вымышленные.
"Будланула" – сделала что-то в один приём.
"Курдячит" – проделывает нечто длительное.
Бокр и бокренок – одушевленные, а не пень и опёнок. Кстати, почему?
А куздра – она живая или нет?

Comment: Вот тут вы ощибаетесь.
Опровержение Щербы давно стало забавою многих поколений филологов.

посмотрите для начала тут  
http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/14661/%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: Где опровержение-то?

Comment: По ссылке.  
Если вы не поняли, основная мысль Щербы была то, что "некорневые" морфы дают достаточно оснований для однозначной интерпретации грамматики фразы.

Comment: Совершенно верно. И где опровержение этого?! Ну, ткните носом, плз.

Comment: По  ссылке  опровержения  не  нашлось. То,  что  там  есть  на  опровержение  не  тянет.

Comment: "Опровержение" - во фразах, имеющих другую грамматику.
Неужели непонятно?